# Can't access to variables of my widget flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, text, widget, nosuchmethoderror

I try to make an simple profil page for my application but I don't exactly know how to do it.

I have an error when I want to call

```
'${widget.user['first_name']}'
```

in my profil widget:

`NoSuchMethodError (NoSuchMethodError: The method '[]' was called on null. Receiver: null Tried calling: []("first_name"))`

My main page is a PageView that contains 2 widgets.

```
// ignore_for_file: prefer_const_constructors, prefer_const_literals_to_create_immutables

import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:clic_ads/Login/apiClient.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';
import '../Composants/appbar.dart';
import '../Login/login.dart';
import 'notifs.dart';
import 'profil.dart';

class MainPage extends StatefulWidget {
  final dynamic user;
  const MainPage({super.key, this.user});
  @override
  _MainPageState createState() => _MainPageState();
}

class _MainPageState extends State<MainPage> {
  final Api _apiClient = Api();
  dynamic user;
  final PageController _controller = PageController(
    initialPage: 0,
  );
  int activePage = 0;

  @override
  Future<void> dispose() async {
    _controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }
  
@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }
  void bottomTapped(int index) {
    setState(() {
      activePage = index;
      _controller.animateToPage(index,
          duration: Duration(milliseconds: 500), curve: Curves.ease);
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Future<void> getUser() async {
      SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
      var token = prefs.getString('token');
      this.user = await _apiClient.user(token!);
      print(user);
      return user ;
    }
    getUser();
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: PreferredSize(
          preferredSize:
              Size.fromHeight(MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.07),
          child: TopAppbar()),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
        currentIndex: activePage,
        backgroundColor: const Color(0xffC64C4E),
        selectedItemColor: Colors.white,
        unselectedItemColor: Colors.white.withOpacity(.55),
        selectedFontSize: 14,
        unselectedFontSize: 14,
        onTap: (value) {
          bottomTapped(value);
        },
        items: [
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            label: 'Notifs',
            icon: Icon(Icons.view_list),
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            label: 'Profil',
            icon: Icon(
              Icons.account_circle,
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
      backgroundColor: const Color(0xffEEEEEE),
      body: PageView(
        onPageChanged: (index) {
          setState(() {
            activePage = index;
          });
        },
        controller: _controller,
        children: [Notifs(), Profil(user: this.user)],
      ),
    );
  }
  
}
```

My first widget is an widget to show notifications :

```
// ignore_for_file: prefer_const_constructors, prefer_const_literals_to_create_immutables, unnecessary_new

import 'package:clic_ads/Login/apiClient.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';

class Notifs extends StatefulWidget {
final dynamic user;
const Notifs({super.key, this.user});

@override
State\<Notifs\> createState() =\> \_NotifsState();
}

class \_NotifsState extends State\<Notifs\> {
final Api \_apiClient = Api();
dynamic user;
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
double deviceWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
double deviceHeight = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
Future\<void\> getUser() async {
SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
var token = prefs.getString('token');
this.user = await \_apiClient.user(token!);
print(user);
return user ;
}
getUser();

    return ListView.builder(
      itemCount: 10,
      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
        return Column(
          children: [
            new Container(
              decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                  color: Color.fromARGB(255, 255, 255, 255),
                  borderRadius: new BorderRadius.only(
                    topRight: const Radius.circular(15.0),
                    topLeft: const Radius.circular(15.0),
                  )),
              margin: EdgeInsets.only(
                  top: deviceWidth * 0.03,
                  right: deviceWidth * 0.05,
                  left: deviceWidth * 0.05),
              height: deviceHeight * 0.148,
              alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
              child: Row(
                children: [
                  Container(
                    decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                        color: const Color(0xffC64C4E),
                        borderRadius: new BorderRadius.only(
                          topLeft: const Radius.circular(15.0),
                        )),
                    width: deviceWidth * 0.12,
                    child: Center(
                      child: FittedBox(
                        child: Text(
                          'CU',
                          style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: deviceWidth * 0.06,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                              color: Colors.white),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(deviceWidth * 0.02),
                    child: SizedBox(
                      width: deviceWidth * 0.73,
                      child: Column(
                        children: [
                          Row(
                            children: [
                              Text('17:24',
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                      fontSize: deviceWidth * 0.04,
                                      color: const Color(0xffC64C4E),
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w600)),
                              Spacer(),
                              Text('20/10/2022',
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                      fontSize: deviceWidth * 0.04,
                                      color: const Color(0xffC64C4E),
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w600))
                            ],
                          ),
                          Padding(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.all(deviceWidth * 0.02),
                            child: Row(
                              children: [
                                Icon(Icons.person),
                                Text('DUPOND Martin (M.)',
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                        fontSize: deviceWidth * 0.035,
                                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w500))
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                          Padding(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.all(deviceWidth * 0.02),
                            child: Row(
                              children: [
                                Icon(
                                  Icons.book,
                                ),
                                Text('CU01201222U0009',
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                        fontSize: deviceWidth * 0.035,
                                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w500))
                              ],
                            ),
                          )
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
            Container( 
                color: const Color(0xffC64C4E),
                height: 3,
                width: deviceWidth * 0.90)
          ],
        );
      },
    );

}
}
```

And my second widget where I want to show the user details is here :

```
// ignore_for_file: prefer_const_constructors, prefer_const_literals_to_create_immutables

import 'package:clic_ads/Login/apiClient.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';

class Profil extends StatefulWidget {
final dynamic user;
const Profil({super.key, this.user});
@override
State\<Profil\> createState() =\> \_ProfilState();
}

class \_ProfilState extends State\<Profil\> {

// final Api \_apiClient = Api();
@override
void initState() {
super.initState();
}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    // Future<void> getUser() async {
    //   SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    //   var token = prefs.getString('token');
    //   user = await _apiClient.user(token!);
    //   print(user['data']);
    // }
    
    // getUser();
    // print(user);
    double deviceWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    double deviceHeight = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    
    return Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(deviceWidth * 0.05),
      child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          Text('Profil',
              style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: deviceWidth * 0.06, fontWeight: FontWeight.w500)),
          Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: deviceWidth * 0.05),
            child: Row(
              children: [
                Icon(
                  Icons.account_circle,
                  size: deviceWidth * 0.3,
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: deviceWidth * 0.05),
                  child: Column(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: [
                      Row(
                        children: [
                          Text('${widget.user['first_name']}',
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: deviceWidth * 0.04,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w500)),
                          SizedBox(width: 10),
                          Text('${widget.user['last_name']}',
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: deviceWidth * 0.04,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w500))
                        ],
                      ),
                      SizedBox(
                        height: 15,
                      ),
                      Text('${widget.user['email']}',
                          style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: deviceWidth * 0.04,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.w500))
                    ],
                  ),
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),
          Text('Paramètres',
              style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: deviceWidth * 0.06, fontWeight: FontWeight.w500))
        ],
      ),
    );

}
}
```

I expect to show my user informations on my profil page.

Answer (score 0):

In the `'${widget.user['first_name']}'` line in your second code sample, where is the user info being grabbed from? To me, it seems that there is no instance of the current user to get information from.

Comment: Thx for your answer

In my MainPage Widget, I call an API in my function getUser().
I pass the result of the function in the argument of my Profil widget

Answer (score 0):

Try accepting null like

```dart
'${widget.user?['first_name']}'
```

Answer (score 0):

The `getUser();` method is async method but it is not awaited during the `_MainPageState.build` method execution.

So when `children: [Notifs(), Profil(user: this.user)],` line is executed the `user` class member is not initialized.

So probably you may want to use the [FutureBuilder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html) to await the future and get result.

This solution requires `getUser` method to be adjusted as the class method and to return the `Future<dynamic>` value to be used later:

```dart
class _NotifsState extends State<Notifs> {
...
Future<dynamic> getUser() async {
SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
var token = prefs.getString('token');
this.user = await _apiClient.user(token!);
print(user);
return user ;
}

@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
...
children: [Notifs(), FutureBuilder<dynamic>(
        future: getUser(), 
        builder: (c, snapshot) => snapshot.hasData
            ? Profil(user: snapshot.data) 
            : const CircularProgressIndicator())
],
}
}
```